# Machine Learning, why not use matrix multiplication instead of gradient descent?

Tags: matrices, regression, machine-learning, descent

If we want to minimize our Cost function for a given set of data, why do we use gradient descent and continually guess values until we find a min value for theta when when can just use matrix multiplication to solve for theta with the equation:

$$a = (M^T M)^{-1} M^T y$$

where ${}^T$ means "transpose" and $a$ is the column matrix of Theta values.

Comment: If you'd like to learn how to typeset mathematically, I suggest taking a look at the following tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is that for optimization problems over big matrices, matrix-inversion can be very computationally expensive, and so avoiding inversion becomes an important time-saving and space-saving measure.  For a sufficiently small set of data, you might be better off directly finding $(M^T M)^{-1}$.

Comment: Additionally, if $M$ has both very small and very large singular values, $M^TM$ may turn out to be singular, even if $M$ has a full column rank.